# PHP Echo URL - add target?

Tags: php

I can't seem to add a target to the URL without getting an error :/
Could anyone please be so kind to help out? Thanks!

```
<?php 
echo "<a href=\"".$banner[$random]['link']."\"><img src=\"".$banner[$random]['img']."\" border=\"0\"></a>";
//result
?>
```

I've tried this solution;

```
echo "<a href=\"".$banner[$random]['link']."\"><img src=\"".$banner[$random]['img']."\" border=\"0\".'" target="_blank"></a>";
```

This is the full code (it's a random image + URL script):

```
<?php 
$banner[1]['link'] = "http://www.url.com";
$banner[1]['img'] = "/banners/square_1.jpg";

$banner[2]['link'] = "http://url.com";
$banner[2]['img'] = "/banners/square_2.jpg";

//number of banners
$banners=2; 

srand((double)microtime()*1000000);     

$random = rand(1,$banners);     

echo "<a href=\"".$banner[$random]['link']."\"><img src=\"".$banner[$random]['img']."\" border=\"0\"></a>";
//result
?>
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-rand.php

Comment: Just an observation, but if your PHP version is 4.2.0 or higher, you don't need srand().

Comment: there is no problem with this script, so we can't guess what you want, some minor things you could change (but won't cause problems) are: you don't need srand if you are using php version above 4.2 and you can use http://php.net/mt_rand also instead of rand();

Comment: I've tried 

echo "<a href=\"".$banner[$random]['link']."\"><img src=\"".$banner[$random]['img']."\" border=\"0\"." target="_blank"></a>";

I'm pretty bad at php, but thought it would have been easy to find/google.

Comment: We need to know the error. Also `sprintf`/`printf`/`strtr` are your friends.. especially for html generation.

Comment: @MikeK. You were trying to add `target="_blank"` to the image; not to to the link where you were supposed to... :-) - So, simply by moving it to your `a` tag, instead of your `img` tag, would work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use:

```
echo "<a href=\"{$banner[$random]['link']}\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"{$banner[$random]['img']}\" border=\"0\"></a>";
```

I'm a big fan of the curly brackets for readability.

But I'd, personally, do it like:

```
echo "<a href='{$banner[$random]['link']}' target='_blank'><img src='{$banner[$random]['img']}' border='0'></a>";
```

for even easier readability.

Comment: This does exactly the same thing as his code (and adds a `target="_blank"`)

Comment: That's exactly what he asked for.. a **target**

Comment: Well, that's an interpretation but (still guessing) I think he is refering to the `href` part. (in his code, he doesn't seem like he tried to add `target="_blank"`...)

Comment: IF this is what he wanted (we'll see), I definitely... give up :-)

Comment: Holy beep; yes that was it ... LOL :-)

Comment: It wasn't me. (I'm out of votes for today actually). Though your comment is still valid... :-)

Comment: Jep, great that works, blame my bad php skills.
Thanks for the srand() comment as well!
Mike

Comment: Mike, do me a favor and mark question as answered and upvote it, so it's not negative? Thanks.